# Implementing profile picture cropper into social network

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a social network as a learning project and I am stuck at profile picture uploading. I would like to make users upload picture, crop it to specific size (605x600px), then save it to a local server folder and preview it on the profile page.

Can someone help me build such cropping tool or guide me where I can get something like that? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to crop it? That's a bit mean in my opinion. Maybe look in to resize instead?

Comment: I would like it to be square looking, because that is how profile picture will look. I am thinking about cropping because i don't want to change original aspect of the photo, if there is a better solution than cropping, I'd reconsider it.